# Which operator is called in that case

Tags: c++

When there is a construction like this:

```
Foo f;  
f->bar(); //Here is called the class member access operator
```

But when 'f' is a pointer to a object of type Foo:

```
Foo* f = new Foo();  
(*f)->bar(); //Here is also called the class member access operator  
f->bar(); //<-- Which operator is called?  
//Is it the pointer to member one (->*),  
//or is the pointer-dereference one, or maybe both of them?
```

And I also want to ask can this behaviour be overloaded?

```
...  
class Foo{
    ...
    Foo* operator->() const{
        cout << "overloaded" << endl;
        return this;
    }
};
Foo a;  
Foo* b = new Foo();  
a->bar(); //Here is called the overloaded -> 
(*b)->(); //Again the overloaded one  
b->bar(); //This calls something else
```

Comment: `Foo f; f.bar()` should be in first example.

Comment: @TomaszKłak The first example is fine, it will call the overloaded `->` operator.

Comment: Even if the question is interesting, that code is awful :(

Comment: What does `this doesn't work` mean? Does `Foo` have a function named `bar()`?

Comment: The return type of `operator->()` should not be `Foo`, it should be a pointer or another type implementing `operator->`. Returning `Foo` won't compile because it will try calling `operator->` on the same type infinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overload the `->` operator on pointers. When `p` is a pointer, `p->bar()` will dereference the pointer and call the `bar` function on the object. It will not call any overloaded operators.

On the other hand, `(*p)->bar()` will call the overloaded `->` operator on the pointed-to type.

Comment: And also '.' operator can not be overloaded under any circumstances.